# Python - How to display a single data point on a scatter plot?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to display a 3D scatter plots. The code below works but it displays the current and old data points. I would like to display only one at a time. I've tried different options but I can't get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_zlim(0, 1.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

data = [[-1.0, -1.0, 0.0], [1.0, -1.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

def animate(data):

    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    z = data[2]

    scat = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, data, interval=1000, blit=False, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the axes in each iteration in the `for` loop. Note that you need to take care of the axes limits as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_zlim(0, 1.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

data = [[-1.0, -1.0, 0.0], [1.0, -1.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

def animate(data):

    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    z = data[2]

    plt.cla()
    ax.set_xlim([-1.5,1.5])
    ax.set_ylim([-1.5,1.5])
    ax.set_zlim([-1.5,1.5])
    scat = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, data, interval=1000, blit=False, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems to only work if you aren't plotting anything else. For example, I need to plot a line whose head is a scatter point. If I clear the axis, I lose the line which is behavior I do not want.